# TypeScript - Arrays within Arrays - Push new Object into specific array

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have what I believe is a 2D array, generated via the below.

```
export class ItemClass
{
    ItemId: number;
    Name: string;
    Units: number;
}
```

---

```
var masterItemArray: any[] = [];

var itemArray: ItemClass[] = [];

let item: ItemClass;

item = new ItemClass();
item.ItemId = 100;
item.Name = "Item 1";
item.Units = 2;
itemArray.push(item);

item = new ItemClass();
item.ItemId = 100;
item.Name = "Item 2";
item.Units = 5;
itemArray.push(item);

masterItemArray.push(itemArray);

var itemArray1: ItemClass[] = [];

item = new ItemClass();
item.ItemId = 200;
item.Name = "Item 1";
item.Units = 4;
itemArray1.push(item);

item = new ItemClass();
item.ItemId = 200;
item.Name = "Item 2";
item.Units = 8;
itemArray1.push(item);

masterItemArray.push(itemArray1);
```

This then creates a 2D array such as the below

```
[
    {
       {ItemId = 100, Name = "Item 1", Units = 2},
       {ItemId = 100, Name = "Item 2", Units = 5}
    },
    {
       {ItemId = 200, Name = "Item 1", Units = 4},
       {ItemId = 200, Name = "Item 2", Units = 8}
    }
]
```

My question is i want to be able to push another `ItemClass` object into say the second array within the array (where the `ItemId = 200`), such as..

```
[
    {
       {ItemId = 100, Name = "Item 1", Units = 2},
       {ItemId = 100, Name = "Item 2", Units = 5}
    },
    {
       {ItemId = 200, Name = "Item 1", Units = 4},
       {ItemId = 200, Name = "Item 2", Units = 8},
       {ItemId = 200, Name = "Item 3", Units = 15}
    }
]
```

But I cant seem to get the right code to push this in, for example..

```
var newItemArray= new Item();
newItemArray.ItemId = 200;
newItemArray.Name = "Item 3";
newItemArray.Units = 15;

masterItemArray[1].push(newItemArray);
```

doesn't work, despite the correct index being referenced.

I'm not sure what else can be done, as using intellisense the only options offered are to rename the properties such as `ItemId`, `Name` and `Units`, I'm not offered any array extensions.

Thankyou!

Comment: Any errors? warnings? How did you know it doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry yes, i get

`masterItemArray[1].push is not a function` when i try it out on my page

Comment: Well, seems like your `masterItemArray` is out of scope in place you call push last time. Could you provide full code?

Comment: This really is the full code, apart from the View but that's not in question. Debugging in Chrome shows that the `masterItemArray` contains two inner arrays with the items as above

Comment: Why not just use `.filter`? Seriously, `masterItemArray.filter(x => x[0].itemId === 200)[0].push(newItem);`

Comment: I guess you call your last push in different place (maybe it's some event listener or something). You should provide full methods code. If i copypaste your code in typescript sandbox it works perfectly, it means thats error in other code that you don't provide.

Comment: JaredSmith - nice idea, unfortunately, I get the same`masterItemArray.filter(...)[0].push is not a function`

Comment: @Skaterhaz Then that item is not an array. I would test that with something like this: `let foo = arr.filter(x => x[0].itemId === 200)[0]; console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(foo), (foo && foo.constructor.name));`. If the code were correct you'd see `[object Array], Array`. What you *do* see should tip you off.

Comment: @Maxx & JaredSmith - Thanks guys you were both right and very helpful. It turns out I was trying to push an item to an Object rather than an array.